# How to Auto Generate a code using Codeigniter framework? example for generate member number for a member card

Tags: php, codeigniter, auto-generate

How to make an auto-generated code for member number. I use Codeigniter framework. but it shows some error and all data success entry to the database except "member number" that highlights in error pictured below.

This is my codes:

```
//Model
public function customer_insert($table, $data)
{
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    return $query;
}
public function customer_getByLastId()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT customer_id FROM customer where customer_id=last_insert_id()");
    return $query;
}
public function customer_update($id, $table, $data)
{
    $query = $this->db->where('customer_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->update($table, $data);
    return $query;
}

//Controller
public function add()
{

    $name = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_name'));
    $ktp = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_ktp'));
    $email = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_email'));
    $gender = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_gender'));
    $phone = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_phone'));
    $address = strip_tags($this->input->post('i_address'));

    // Input Array
    $data = array(
        'name'             => $name,
        'ktp'             => $ktp,
        'email'             => $email,
        'gender'             => $gender,
        'phone'             => $phone,
        'address'             => $address
    );

    // Insert ke Database
    $x = $this->customer_model->customer_cek($ktp);

    if ($x == Null) {
        $this->customer_model->customer_insert('customer', $data);

        $id = $this->customer_model->customer_getByLastId();
        $char = "MEM";
        $no_member = $char . sprintf("%09s", $id);

        $data = array(
            'no_member'             => $no_member
        );
        $this->customer_model->customer_update($id, 'customer', $data);

        echo '<script language=JavaScript>alert("Input Berhasil")
            onclick=history.go(-0);</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script language=JavaScript>alert("Gagal!! customer telah tersimpan sebelumnya karena Nama atau dan No. Hp sama!")
            onclick=history.go(-1);</script>';
    }
}
```

Error Like Following:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to
>   string
>
> Filename: admin/Customer.php
>
> Line Number: 46
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tokobuku\application\controllers\admin\Customer.php
>   Line: 46 Function: sprintf
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tokobuku\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to
>   a string
>
> Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php
>
> Line Number: 2442
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tokobuku\application\models\Customer_model.php
>   Line: 32 Function: update
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tokobuku\application\controllers\admin\Customer.php
>   Line: 51 Function: customer_update
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tokobuku\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 2
>
> ## UPDATE `customer` SET `no_member` = 'MEM000000000' WHERE `customer_id`
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/tokobuku/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: Do u want to retrieve the auto generated Id?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Can you share the error?

Comment: Please add the code you want to get reviewed directly in your qestion, posting images makes it so much harder to get an overview. As mentioned above, share the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change this codes in your model then try

```
 //Model
public function customer_insert($table, $data){
   return $this->db->insert($table, $data);
}
public function customer_getByLastId(){
    return  $this->db->query("SELECT customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1 ")->row()->customer_id;    
}
public function customer_update($id, $table, $data){ 
    $this->db->where('customer_id', $id);
     return $this->db->update($table, $data);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the model, it seems that you want to retrieve the last inserted customer Id.If so, you can use this in codeigniter, just after you execute your insert customer query:

`$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();`

You should use transactions in case of multiple inserts:

`$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->trans_complete();`